# Can a website (php) read a csv on a personal onedrive?

Tags: php, html, onedrive

First post.
I have a limited knowledge of php but a good idea about html.

At the moment I am building the site so that I can read a csv in to a table from some code I discovered online and works great at the moment (I am building it on my hard drive and using xampp so the php works).

This is the code I have to read a csv

```
<p><?php
// Open the CSV file
$fcsv = fopen( 'csv/test.csv', 'r' );
// Get header row
$row = fgetcsv( $fcsv );
// Output start of table & header row
?>
<table border="1">
  <thead align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><?= $row[0] ?></td> 
      <!-- <td><?= $row[1] ?></td> This column is not needed hence being commented out -->
      <td><?= $row[2] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[3] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[4] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[5] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[6] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[7] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[8] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[9] ?></td> 
      <td><?= $row[10] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[11] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[12] ?></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
// Loop through rest of rows in CSV
while ( ( $row = fgetcsv( $fcsv ) ) !== false )
{
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $row[0] ?></td>
      <!-- <td><?= $row[1] ?></td> Not needed as this is the class number -->
      <td><?= $row[2] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[3] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[4] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[5] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[6] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[7] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[8] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[9] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[10] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[11] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row[12] ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php
}
?>
  </tbody>
</table>>
```

If I was at work on a lunchbreak and I updated a csv with info, and uploaded to my one drive it would not be seen unless they were linked.
I cannot access any sort of ftp from my work computers.
I can access my own onedrive from my work computer via a browser.

I really haven't got a clue on hos to do this so help with how to and code would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: **unless they were linked** - Do you mean unless you `sync` the onedrive file with your local copy ?

Comment: Not really.
If the website had the php page can it read the csv from the onedrive. So when a newer version of the is uploaded then it shows when someone goes on the page

Comment: You need to use PHP to interact programmatically with the OneDrive REST API . Either you write it yourself or use SDK like [this](https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk)

Comment: Give you one more [alternative](https://github.com/calebdevelop/onedrive-api-for-php) API

Comment: Thanks Ken,
I'll take a look at that later